# Linear function over a linear space of functions

Tags: real-analysis

let $L$ be the space of linear functions from $\Bbb{R}$ to a normed vector space $F$. Let $I$ be a linear map from $L$ to $F$ defined as an application which assigns to each linear function of $L$ the value at $1$. I have to prove that $I$ is bijective.

I first tried to prove that $I$ is one-to-one: let $f$ and $g$ be two different functions of $L$. Using the linearity of $I$ i come to the conclusion: $I(f)-I(g)= f(1)-g(1)$. We can think of the linear functions as straight lines. In the general case we can find such functions $f$ and $g$ which do intersect at $1$. So $f(1)-g(1)$ might eventually vanish which would mean that $I$ is not one-to-one. I couldn't come further if i look at the $Ker(I)$.
I'll be pleased if somebody gives me a hint. How about the surjectivity of $I$ ?

Thanks for any comment.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that thinking linear functions from $\Bbb R$ to $F$ as straight lines is not a good idea.

In fact, if $f(1)=g(1)$ then $f(x)=xf(1)=xg(1)=g(x)$ for each $x\in\Bbb R$. So $f$ and $g$ are the same function. You can also use dimension. Since $\Bbb R$ is of dimension $1$ over itself, a linear function from $\Bbb R$ to $F$ is determined by the value at $1$. (Or in fact, at any nonzero value).

To show surjectivity, just take any $\mathbf v\in F$. Define $f(t)=t\mathbf v$ for $x\in\Bbb R$. Is $f$ linear? What is $I(f)$?

Comment: Thanks for the excellent hints. f is linear and I(f)=f(1)=v.  If F is a discrete space ( eventually finite ) would the statement still hold ?

Comment: When considering linear functios from a vector space $V$ into another vector space $W$, it is assumed that base fields of both are the same. Otherwise, the linearity condition $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$ would not make sense. So the base field of $F$ is $\Bbb R$ and this prevents it to be finite or discrete, unless $F=\{0\}$ which has little interest anyway. BTW, the best way to say thanks here is upvoting and / or accepting :)